Pivot pandas table into multiple columns
Good day,
I wish to transform my dataFrame into wide format by a grouping variable. Like this:
Group_var |type |value
1         |11    | 111
1         |12    | 111
2         |22    | 222
3         |33    | 333
3         |34    | 334
3         |35    | 335

Into following format:
Group_var |type_1 |value_1 |type_2 |value_2|type_3 |value_3
1         |11    | 111     |12     | 111   |       |
2         |22    | 222     |       |       |       |
3         |33    | 333     |34     | 334   |35     |335

Yeach group_var has differing amount of values and types making pivoting a problem. Any ideas how to do this?

Something like this? https://onecompiler.com/python/42fw2g2jw

What about using pivot_table with an aggregate function of list then explode it and concatenate type and value dataframe values:
df = df.pivot_table(values=['type', 'value'], index='Group_var', aggfunc=list)
df = pd.concat([df[c].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(c + "_") for c in df], axis=1).reset_index()

print(df)

Output:
   Group_var  type_0  type_1  type_2  value_0  value_1  value_2
0          1    11.0    12.0     NaN    111.0    111.0      NaN
1          2    22.0     NaN     NaN    222.0      NaN      NaN
2          3    33.0    34.0    35.0    333.0    334.0    335.0


The following code should achieve what you are trying to do:
def my_func(gp):
     return list(range(1, len(gp)+1))

df1 = df.stack().reset_index().groupby(['Group_var', 'level_1']).agg(my_func)[0].explode().reset_index(level=1)
df2 = (df1['level_1'] + '_' + df1[0].astype('str')).reset_index().drop('Group_var', axis='columns').rename(columns={0: 'col_names'})
df3 = df.stack().sort_index(level=[0, 1]).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis='columns').rename(columns={0: 'val'})
pd.merge(left=df3, right=df2, left_index=True, right_index=True).set_index(['Group_var', 'col_names']).unstack(level=1).droplevel(level=0, axis='columns')

Which gives the output
col_names  type_1  type_2  type_3  value_1  value_2  value_3
Group_var                                                   
1            11.0    12.0     NaN    111.0    111.0      NaN
2            22.0     NaN     NaN    222.0      NaN      NaN
3            33.0    34.0    35.0    333.0    334.0    335.0

Though I think you should use stack method instead of trying to create an ever-increasing dataframe
df.stack()

Which gives the output:
Group_var       
1          type      11
           value    111
           type      12
           value    111
2          type      22
           value    222
3          type      33
           value    333
           type      34
           value    334
           type      35
           value    335
dtype: int64

